# How to read SD card CID on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, usb, sd-card, memory-card, bus

Is there is a tool/way that one can read the CID of a SD card under Windows 10?

My laptop card reader seem to be plugged to USB bus rather than PCI bus if this matters.

[image]

Comment: I am looking for CID not serial number.

Comment: After further research it looks like you cannot read the cid if it is mounted as a usb device>>>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50981056/read-cid-of-sdcard-connected-to-usb-sd-reader-under-linux

Comment: I did find this>>>https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-read-a-cid-on-an-sd-card

Comment: Looks like you may need special hardware>>>>https://www.peshaqu.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=741007

Answer (score 2):

To get **CID** you need to send **CMD10** to SD card and get 16bytes reply.

It looks most of Realtek card readers support SD commands via vendors' extension to USBMS protocol working via USB. But in most Realtek drivers, only **CMD9** and **CMD13** are processed.

For CMD10, the driver returns a default of zeroes, as do all other unsupported commands.

So to get things working you need to patch the driver for example by replacing CMD9 with CMD10 and a user-side application to use Windows API call to **DeviceIoControl** with **SFFDISK_COMMAND** control code with command10 parameters. Also after driver patching it will lose signing and Windows 10 will only start it in special boot modes allowing it to run non-digitally signed kernel drivers. Sample command line application and sample patched driver available at https://github.com/DTL2020/SDcard . If possible it is good to make a petition to Realtek to make and release WHQL digitally signed driver with the support of CMD10 for reading of CID of SD cards.

Answer (score 1):

The techwalla link isn't helpful and the software mentioned doesn't work because to read a CID # you need specific hardware you can pass a specific vendor command to fetch the value.

[www.nexcopy.com/sd-duplicator/](https://www.nexcopy.com/sd-duplicator/) can read CID numbers.  It's a duplicator tho... so probably not viable for a single use situation.  But can certainly do it... and in bulk.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).